# A shorter way to describe a cave path of a certain length

Tags: word-choice, phrase-request

As I have to divide caves into some groups, I need to classify them as:

1. caves with short path (below 100 m)
2. caves with middle path (between 100 - 200 m)
3. caves with very long path

What are the shorter words for those classification?

Comment: Caves are not always linear-- they are generally a system of connected chambers which may be arranged in an odd shape, with no clear "path" to speak of.

Comment: I wonder if *passage* would be a better word choice (than *path*).

Comment: Does *path* mean how far you can walk inside the cave? I would use *walkway* in that case.

Comment: Also "*a* short path", etc.

Comment: Caves are connected by **passages**. Usually the distance referred to in a cave is its actual measurement usually in meters, yards, or feet (as it is in mountain climbing).  Lack of precision is usually not a good thing in caves.

Comment: How about *1:Shallow cave, 2:Cave, 3:Deep cave?*

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't think the size of a cave system necessarily corresponds to how deep it goes - it could be a shallow system of caves that extends for miles. I would think that a deep cave would necessarily have long passages though.

Comment: I believe the question needs clarification. Does the original question use "path" to refer to depth, or to length? The question makes sense if one substitutes "depth" in the place of "path", but "path" would more likely be used as a substitute for "length". The question does not make sense using the word path, and it is only marginally sensible if one substitutes "length" in place of "path".

Comment: @CorvusB This poster asked about the length of the path in  http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/82185/ which I read first so I knew what they were asking. You're right that it could use some clarification, especially with the choice of "below 100m" to describe short.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a specific set of words for a cave passage, so you will just want to use comparative descriptions of length.

I might group them as **"short", "typical", and "long"**. You could also use "medium" instead of typical as Jay suggested, especially if people might have different ideas of what a medium length cave system is.

Using these terms allows for a lot of interpretation of exactly how long a passageway you're describing if you don't specify it in your paper. You could say something like:

> "The cave systems were divided into three groups, those with short passageways (less than 100 m), those with typical length passageways (100-200 m), and those with long passageways (greater than 200 m).

After that you may just refer to them as "short systems", "typical systems", and "long systems" I think.

Comment: +1, though I'd say "medium" rather than "typical". It's pretty standard to categorize things as short/medium/long. And the middle range may or may not be "typical".

Comment: @Jay The reason I choose typical because I thought it might be a point of reference for folks familiar with cave systems, but medium was what I thought of first, so I went ahead and edited it in.

Comment: If one assumes that the OP meant "passage" or "passageway" when they used "path", this is an excellent answer.